# Removing while iterating issues in java

Tags: java

I want to implement a method attack that works like this: every warrior from my troop attacks an warrior chosen randomly from another troop. If the attacked warrior dies it must be removed from the troop. With the method that i tried i get the error for the random number:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive
```

The troop is a List `<Creature>` warriors; I think that i am not doing the remove correctly, because otherwise i should not have that error.

```
public void atac(Troop opponentTroop){
        for(Creature f : warriors){
            Creature c = getOpponent(opponentTroop);
            f.atac(c);
            ListIterator<Creature> iterator = opponentTroop.warriors.listIterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                c = iterator.next();
                if(c.isDead()){
                    iterator.remove();                  
                }
            }   

        }       
    }


private Creature getOpponent(Troop opponent){
        int x = rand.getRandomArrayIndex(opponent.warriors.size());
        return opponent.warriors.get(x);
}
```

Comment: Can you give us the very line where the exception is thrown (see Stacktrace)?

Comment: Where is the `IllegalArgumentException` being thrown from?  I don't recognise it as a standard Java error message, so it may be being thrown by some other part of you application.  The problem might not be iteration but logic in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the entry invalidates the iterator. You need to save it, you could do something like this:

```
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    c = iterator.next();
    if(c.isDead()) {
        // Make a temporary iterator
        ListIterator<Creature> toDelete= c;
        // Step the regular one
        c = iterator.next();
        // Remove
        toDelete.remove();                  
    }
}
```

Also, make sure `int x = rand.getRandomArrayIndex(opponent.warriors.size());` never goes beyond the last index (which is the number of entries **minus one**.

Comment: I think I would choose to add the dead opponent to a new list. In an extra loop the dead opponents would be deleted. It is likely that there needs to be done more to the dead opponents, like an animation process or something for all the dead bodies

Comment: @Raymond van Dongelen: Actually there is no need for an extra loop. She could just call `opponentTroop.warriors.removeAll(toDelete)`